# Java - Error creating a functional interface with an

Tags: java, generics

I have the below test class in my java code:

```
 Function<? super Either<? extends Object, ? extends Object>, ? super Either<? extends Object, ? extends Object>> test = new Function<Either<Integer, Integer>, Either<Integer, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Either<Integer, Integer> apply(Either<Integer, Integer> integers) {
            return integers;
        }
 }
```

Documentation for Either can be found here: http://static.javadoc.io/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.0.2/javaslang/control/Either.html.

But I get the following compile error (Java 8)

```
Error:(77, 129) java: incompatible types: 
<anonymous java.util.function.Function<javaslang.control.Either<java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer>,javaslang.control.Either<java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer>>> 
cannot be converted to 
java.util.function.Function<? super javaslang.control.Either<? extends java.lang.Object,? extends java.lang.Object>,? super javaslang.control.Either<? extends java.lang.Object,? extends java.lang.Object>>
```

I am new to Java and am not sure what is wrong here. Any help is much appreciated.

I understand this code does not make sense and that is not how I am using it really. I am actually trying to pass a Function to an internal library. But I should not be getting that compile error where Either cannot be converted to ? super Either

Thanks!!

Comment: You are new to java, but you try to use generics in a very advanced way; my suggestion: step back and look into the things that newbies to the Java language would start with ;-)

Comment: Tip: `? extends Object` is synonymous with `?`.

Comment: Why don't you just declare your variable as the type you create? I.e. `Function<Either<Integer, Integer>, Either<Integer, Integer>>`

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because `? super Either<? extends Object, ? extends Object>` (which is equivalent to `? super Either<?, ?>`) must be able to accept *any* type of `Either`. For example, the following must compile

```
Either<Long, Long> either = ...
test.apply(either);
```

since `Either<Long, Long>` is a subclass of `Either<?, ?>`. But your implementation is only capable of processing a specific subtype: `Either<Integer, Integer>`.

Here's a simpler demonstration of the same problem:

```
Lis<? super Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This does not compile because the list must be of a type that can accept *any* `Number`, not just `Integer`.

The ideal solution for your case depends on what exactly you're trying to do, which isn't entirely clear from the question. The closest I can get to your attempt is this:

```
Function<? super Either<Integer, Integer>, ? extends Either<?, ?>> test = ...
```

Note the use of `super` in the first parameter and `extends` in the second parameter. This follows the principle of [Producer `extends`, Consumer `super`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/1553851).